# how can I delete duplicate records from my database

Tags: mysql, database

I'm using this query to list duplicate records

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1 from table
group by column1 HAVING count(column1) > 1
```

for my specific query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ReportingDetailID from reportingdetail group by ReportingDetailID  HAVING count(ReportingDetailID) > 1;
```

works great!

now I need to delete duplicate entries, to end up with nice and clean table

I'm looking at the query here

```
DELETE FROM table_name 
USING table_name, table_name AS vtable 
WHERE 
    (table_name.id > vtable.id) 
AND (table_name.req_field=req_field)
```

According to query author "Replace req_field and table_name - should work without any issues"

I just don't understand how can I get it to work on my db

my table name is **reportingdetail** and column name is **reportingdetailID**

```
+-------------------+
| ReportingDetailID |
+-------------------+
|         664602311 | 
|         664602311 | 
|         664602311 | 
|         664602311 | 
+-------------------+
```

Delete all duplicates but keep one

Thank you

Comment: If two rows share the same id, how do you know which one you want to delete, or do you care?

Comment: the problem is that when generating reports it will the same ID will show up more than once! makes our reports useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic principle to delete the duplicate rows...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptbl AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM myTabs;
DELETE FROM myTabs;
INSERT INTO myTabs SELECT * FROM tmptbl;
```

For above I have `myTabs` as Table with `Id` as column where `Id` were duplicated.

Please do changes as per your requirement...

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but my stupid archiving engine, didn't like it :S

Comment: its my arching engine limitation, as the free version doesn't allow you to do INSERT from another table, just so they can get you to buy the enterprise version. 
however your method works with other engines;

Answer (score 0):

```
    create temporary table records_to_delete (id int(11) unsigned primary key);

    insert into records_to_delete 
    ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT ReportingDetailID from reportingdetail 
    group by ReportingDetailID  
    HAVING count(ReportingDetailID) > 1 
    );

    delete from reportingdetail 
    where ReportingDetailID in 
    ( 
    select id from records_to_delete 
    );
```

sorry, did not checked for syntax, etc, but idea should be clear

Comment: Hey thanks Joshua! 
I'm using mysql archiving engine called infinidb to house millions of records the problem with this silly engine it doesn't use primary keys  and it doesn't like the above query. 

I was hoping if we could reverse the first query in a way to keep all records and delete duplicates, not the other way around. 

appreciate your efforts!

Comment: (Just a note, this wasn't my answer, I edited it for the other guy)

Answer (score -3):

```
DELETE FROM table_name 
USING table_name, table_name AS vtable 
WHERE table_name.id > vtable.id
AND table_name.req_field=req_field
```