# Can I do a mysql command to filter and delete duplicated entry

Tags: mysql, count

I have table as `linkage` with below values

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ company_id +  industry +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+     1      +    a      +
+     1      +    b      +
+     2      +    a      +
+     2      +    c      +
+     3      +    a      +
+     4      +    c      +
+     5      +    a      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Is there a way that i can group my industry to get the top count sort by desc order example.

```
a = count 4
c = count 2
b = count 1
```

then delete duplicated industry leaving only the industry that has the higher count for each `company_id`.

---

### Edit 1

This edit is based on OP comment `I wish to only have the industry with the highest count, and deleting the rest of the entry for the same company_id. say for company_id 1, we will delete the second row, for company_id 2 we will delete the forth row.`

Below is what I have.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ company_id +  industry +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+     1      +    a      +
+     1      +    b      +
+     1      +    c      +
+     2      +    a      +
+     2      +    c      +
+     3      +    a      +
+     4      +    c      +
+     5      +    a      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

as we see in column industry, a has max count, I would like to keep this entry per duplicated company_id and remove rest all enteries.

Consider company_id=1. I would need to remove second and third row.
Consider company_id=2. I would need to remove fifth row.
For id=3,4,5 nothing will happen as those are not duplicated.

So final data that should be there in my table is

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ company_id +  industry +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+     1      +    a      +
+     2      +    a      +
+     3      +    a      +
+     4      +    c      +
+     5      +    a      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Just 1 question. what if I have one more row as 4, b. What would happen with company id 4?

Comment: if same count just use keep either industry and delete the other? possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t6.company_id,t6.industry from
(select t5.company_id,t5.industry,
row_number() over (partition by t5.company_id order by t5.company_id) rn
from 
(select t3.company_id,t4.industry from
(select t2.company_id,max(t2.count) count from(
select m.company_id,m.industry,t1.count from linkage m
join
(select n.industry,count(n.industry) count from linkage n
group by n.industry
order by count desc)t1
on m.industry = t1.industry
order by m.company_id)t2
group by t2.company_id
order by t2.company_id)t3
join
(
select m.company_id,m.industry,t1.count from linkage m
join
(select n.industry,count(n.industry) count from linkage n
group by n.industry
order by count desc)t1
on m.industry = t1.industry
order by m.company_id)t4
on t3.company_id = t4.company_id 
and t3.count = t4.count)t5
)t6
where t6.rn = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SELECT industry, count(industry) as "total" 
FROM linkage 
GROUP BY industry 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

### [Demo at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f3fc/2)

---

### Edit 1

Can you take at look at below question.

[**how can I delete duplicate records from my database**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9637749/1066828)

I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @user1627056 : from the input above, can you tell us what output you are expecting?

Comment: @user1627056 : see my updated answer. I think this is what you are looking for...

Comment: i dont need any output, i want to delete the duplicated values base on the industry count. I wish to only have the industry with the highest count, and deleting the rest of the entry for the same company_id. say for company_id 1, we will delete the second row, for company_id 2 we will delete the forth row.

Answer (score 1):

```
select n.industry,count(n.industry) count from linkage n
group by n.industry
order by count desc
```

---

```
select t3.company_id,t4.industry from
(select t2.company_id,max(t2.count) count from(
select m.company_id,m.industry,t1.count from linkage m
join
(select n.industry,count(n.industry) count from linkage n
group by n.industry
order by count desc)t1
on m.industry = t1.industry
order by m.company_id)t2
group by t2.company_id
order by t2.company_id)t3
join
(
select m.company_id,m.industry,t1.count from linkage m
join
(select n.industry,count(n.industry) count from linkage n
group by n.industry
order by count desc)t1
on m.industry = t1.industry
order by m.company_id)t4
on t3.company_id = t4.company_id 
and t3.count = t4.count
```

### [Demo at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d13f56/1)

Comment: I think this is the answer you want.

Comment: yes, this is working. but I have one question for OP. What if I have additional row as 4,b

Comment: And what do you want then (if some industries have equal totals)? Leave any of (4,'b') and (4,'c'), or leave both of them?

Comment: You can test that.If some industries have equal totals,it will leave both of them.

Comment: ultimately i love to have only 1 industry tagged to 1 company_id base on the highest count, if similar count just use either or. possible?

Comment: Yes，please see the answer I added.If some industries have equal totals,it will leave one by random.

Comment: so how to add in delete from this statement? Sorry, i'm not very good with complicated statements. thanks for your help btw

Comment: You can save the result as a table,then delete from the table.